# Replacement for arguments.callee.name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

Is there a safer alternative to `arguments.callee.name`?

My team is working on a library for Chromecast applications that uses class inheritance heavily. We'd like to ensure that some methods are overridden when the class is extended.

To do so we've came up with a helper function to stub out these methods:

`` const methodNotImplemented = (method) => throw new Error(`Method ${method} not implemented`); ``

Now it would be really cool if we could just do this to avoid passing the method name manually, but I'm getting all kinds of warnings from eslint and such.

`` const methodNotImplemented = (method) => throw new Error(`Method ${method || argument.callee.name} not implemented`); ``

Is this okay since the code will only ever run in Chrome or is there an alternative that anyone knows of?

Example usage:

```
class Base {
// method that should be overridden by application
requiredMethod() { 
    methodNotImlemented(' Base.requiredMethod') 
};

initialize() {
    requiredMethod();
}
```

}

// we want to make sure methods are overridden here

```
class MyPlugin extends Base {
}
```

Comment: [There is](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-stack-trace) but it's not a really good alternative. I'd personally avoid doing that in production code, as it seems quite hacky. But it does work. You could also simply leave the error but remove the mention of the name. The call stack would point you at where it came from. It also seems that you're probably going to benefit more from writing in TypeScript, rather than just JS with lots of OO.

Comment: `a helper function` so ... `methodNotImplemented` is the helper function, and how do you intend to use it?

Comment: How do you use that "*helper function to stub out these methods*"?

Comment: Typescript would be awesome... but we can't use it

Answer (score 0):

Using `new Error().stack` seems to be the best solution. Thanks @vlaz.